# Passing events from Interface parameter to another object

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

I've got a class Monitor that requires a parameter of type MouseListener:

```
class Monitor {

    MouseListener listener;

    public Monitor(MouseListener listener) {

        this.listener = listener;
    }

    void onMouseMoveDetected() {

        System.out.println("You moved the mouse");
    }

    void onMouseDragDetected() {

        System.out.println("You dragged the mouse");
    }
}
```

I've also got a MouseListener that receives events.

```
class Mouse implements MouseListener {

    void onMouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

        doSomething(e);
    }

    void onMouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

        doSomethingElse(e);
    }
}
```

Monitor must receive a MouseListener Object as a parameter. I want to be able to take that parameter and use its events as a trigger for the Monitor events.

That is to say I want the Monitor's onMouseMoveDetected() event to fire whenever the Mouse's onMouseMoved(...) event is fired and the same for the drag variants.

Comment: Hi,, you need a commond actionListener and registerer for both of the end points. You will register monitor to listen to mause events and register mause to trigger a event for listeners. So the common classes will handle the routing. my guess tho, you can find alternatives.

Comment: Still unclear what you want to do. Perhaps you can give an example to elaborate the relationship you wish to achieve between the events and your Monitor class.

Comment: I've revised the OP.

Comment: If `Monitor` receives an Instance of `Mouse`, i guess it means that other class (lets call it class A) is listening to events fired in `Monitor`. If you want `Monitor` to listen to `A`, the structure should be different.  What are you trying to achieve ?